# Spring Programmatic Jdbc Transaction rollback doesn't work

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback

I use spring transaction to include a few db update operation into a single transaction. let say there 2 db updates within a single transaction. the update 1 is successful while the second fails. my problem is when such a case happens, the first db update get committed to db even though the second db update failed which leads to transaction rollback.

XML declaration:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" /> 
<property name="username" value="test" /> 
<property name="password" value="test" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="testDao" class="dao.TestDao">
<constructor-arg >
<ref local="simpleJdbcTemplate" />         
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg >
<ref local="txManager" />         
</constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

java code:

```
public class DaoCallback extends TransactionCallbackWithoutResult {
 protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus arg0) {
try{
    dbUpdate1();
    dbUpdate2();
}catch(Exception e){
    arg0.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

i intentionally make the dbUpdate1 to success and the dbUpdate2 to fail so as the test out whether the rollback really works. When I debug through my code, i can see that the control flow run into the catch exception and the "setRollbackOnly()" method is called.

But when I check the database, I can see the change from dbUpdate1(). So please help explain what is wrong here?

Dara kok,

Answer (score 4):

I've found out the problem. It's not the code i've that cause the problem. it's MySQL data storage configuration. MyISAM doesn't support transaction.

Spring should have shown some kind of error message so that developer can know that a transaction is being called on a database engine without transaction support.

Comment: Could you please add more description to your question (indicating MyISAM)  and mark as answered? (against your answer :))